# Larger tabular when array is loaded

Tags: tables

A simple `tabular` environment

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{array} % <-- uncomment this line

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

produces a slightly different result depending on whether the `array` package is loaded or not, as you can see from the following two pictures:

[image: without array.sty]

[image: with array.sty]

(Upper without `array`, lower with it.) Admittedly a barely ascertainable alteration, 34.55pt vs. 35.75pt, but I'm curious to understand where the difference comes from. The definition of `\@tabarray` in `latex.ltx` contains a `\m@th` which is missing in `array.sty` but this doesn't seem to be relevant (I've tried putting `\mathsurround=0pt` and it made no difference).

Who's the culprit? (Apart from David and Frank `:-)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is one of those but not me.

This is documented behaviour `array` package changes the meaning of `|` so that the table becomes wider by that amount, the standard tabular implementation adds negative space either side of a rule so that a `|` slightly overprints the column to either side (or rather normally it overprints the `\tabcolsep` space).

```
 \begin{macro}{\@arrayrule}
    There is only one incompatibility with the original definition:
    the definition of =\@arrayrule=. In the original a line without
    width\footnote{So the space between \texttt{cc} and \texttt{c|c}
    is equal.}  is created by multiple insertions of
    =\hskip .5\arrayrulewidth=.
    We only insert a vertical line into the
    preamble.  This is done to prevent problems with \TeX's main
    memory when generating tables with many vertical lines in them
    (especially in the case of \textsf{floats}).
```

Comment: I swear I've read the documentation twice before posting the questions `:-(`. Anyway thanks...

Comment: @campa I just added a quote:-) Of course the funny thing reading it now in a world where people routinely load tikz and then plot graphs with thousands of sample points is the reason for the change is to save the memory taken up by (in this case) 6 hskip per row.